# React Router Dom is not working only the route path is changing on the url but the components are not rendering and also i am using saleor framework

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, tsx, saleor

here is the route page named as **Approutes.tsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import  Test1 from "../../components/Test/Test1";
import About from "../../components/About/About";


export const Routes: React.FC = () => (
<Router>
  <Switch>
  <Route exact path='/test' component={Test}/>
  <Route exact path='/aboutus' component={About}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
)
```

the **About.tsx** file

```
import * as React from 'react'


const About: React.FC=()=>{
    return(
        <div><h2>About US PAGE</h2></div>
    )
}
export default About;
```

the **Test.tsx file**

```
const Test: React.FC=()=>{
    return(
        <div><h2>Test PAGE</h2></div>
    )
}
export default Test;
```

*there is no error but still the components are not rendering also i am editing on the saleor-storefront framework with ts*

*i think there is some problem with the tsconfig.json for the paths*
the components are in the
**src/components/Test/Test1**
**src/components/About/About**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom", "esnext"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/@next/components/*"],
      "@components/atoms": ["./src/@next/components/atoms/index.ts"],
      "@components/molecules": ["./src/@next/components/molecules/index.ts"],
      "@components/organisms": ["./src/@next/components/organisms/index.ts"],
      "@components/templates": ["./src/@next/components/templates/index.ts"],
      "@components/containers": ["./src/@next/components/containers/index.ts"],
      "@pages": ["./src/@next/pages/index.ts"],
      "@styles": ["./src/@next/globalStyles/index.ts"],
      "@styles/*": ["./src/@next/globalStyles/*"],
      "images/*": ["./src/images/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./src/@next/utils/*"],
      "@hooks": ["./src/@next/hooks/index.ts"],
      "@hooks/*": ["./src/@next/hooks/*"],
      "@types": ["./src/@next/types/index.ts"],
      "@types/*": ["./src/@next/types/*"],
      "@app/*": ["./src/@next/*"],
      "@locale/*": ["./locale/*"],
      "@temp/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import  Test from "../../components/Test/Test1";

the component name will be Test1.tsx

Comment: yes sorry it will be Test1 but still it is not working